# Using a string to target an object

Tags: javascript, string, object, titanium, appcelerator

I'm relatively new to javascript. I'm using appcelerator's titanium SDK to create a mobile app though, and it uses only javascript.

Anyways, I have a hierarchy menu system that I'm creating. I have data arrays filled with submenu items. Each data array is filled with a different submenu. When I click on a menu item, it receives a variable that lets the application know which data array to load next. Here is a basic example:

```
 var data = [
    {title:'Item 1',subID:'1', hasDetail:true,},
    {title:'Item 2',subID:'1', hasDetail:true,}
 ];

 var data1 = [
  {title:'Child1',subID:'1_1', hasDetail:true},
  {title:'Child2', subID:'1_2', hasDetail: true}
 ];

 var data1_1 = [
   {title:'Grandchild1'},
   {title:'Grandchild2'}
  ];

    // I have a ton of menu items though, so the method I'm using 
    // below is very inefficient:
    if(win.subID == '1'){
       tableview.setData(data1);
    } else if(win.subID == '2'){
       tableview.setData(data2);
    }
```

There are many more menus (1,2,3,4,etc and 1_1,1_2,1_3,2_1,2_2, etc), so the method above of setting the data is extremely inefficient. What I'd like to so is something like this:

```
tableview.setData(data + win.subID);
```

However, I know that data is an array object and subID is a string. How can I combine an object's name with a string, then convert it to refer to an object again?

Thanks, and please let me know if anything above was unclear. I've been struggling with this for a really long time.

EDIT:

Here's what I need in other word's:

I have a string, which I want to use to reference an array.

```
data1 = [
   {value: 1},
   {value: 2}
]
var string = 'data1';
magicStringToArrayFunction(string);
tableview.setData(string);
```

What I need is that magical string to array/object function.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know titanium enough to answer this directly but here's a hint. What's the global object in titanium? You know, if you declare a global variable, what object does that variable belong to?

In a browser environment, the global object is window. Using a global variable or calling a global function is actually accessing properties and calling methods of the window object. So, in a web browser:

```
setTimeout(foo, 10)
// is the same as:
window.setTimeout(foo, 10)
// is the same as:
window['setTimeout'](foo,10)
```

and

```
x = 5
// is the same as:
window.x = 5
// is the same as:
window['x'] = 5
```

So in your case, if this were a regular web browser, your code would be:

```
var string = 'data1';
tableview.setData(window[string]);
```

Not all javascript implementations work this way though, this works on all known web browsers with javascript support. Don't know if you can do this in titanium.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is an array of arrays so you can do this...

```
tableView.setData(data[win.subID]);
```

Comment: That would work if each data set was a part of a larger array. However, each array is a separate array completely, called data1, data2, data1_1, etc. I have a string with the number of the array I need to display, but I don't know how to use that string to actually target that array.

Comment: I edited my original post with another example. Hopefully that clears the issue up.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a more elegant way of doing this but I'm tired :] 
But you could use hash tables as a solution

[Javascript hash tables](http://www.mojavelinux.com/articles/javascript_hashes.html)

```
var myArray = new Array();
myArray['data1_1'] = data1_1;
myArray['data1'] = data1;
myArray['data'] = data;

var thestring='data1';
tableview.setData(myArray[thestring]);
```

Something like that may do the trick.